# Can I install Windows server and enble Hyper-V on a VM on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, hyper-v

Can I enable Hyper-V role on windows Guest OS(VM) running on Ubuntu 14.04.

I hitting with issue

`Hyper-V cannot be installed: A hypervisor is already running.`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible to my knowledge.  Xen and KVM don't support Hyper-V in a VM.

Hyper-V is a type 1 hypervisor. It runs on bare metal then runs the parent as if it's a privileged VM.  We've been doing a lot of work recently around nested virtualization ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting)) on a Hyper-V host but nothing for Hyper-V on other hypervisors as of now.

Note:  I work on the Hyper-V team at Microsoft.